# Is it possible to submit a POST, not AJAX, and get a JSON response in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, vb.net, post

I'm trying to submit a form post to another site and gather the JSON response it displays. I'm using the following but I'm unsure how to get the response.

```
$("form input[type=submit]").on("click", function (ev) {
    var result = '';
    ev.preventDefault();
    $('#myform').submit();
});
```

I would have used `.post()` or `.ajax()`; however, best I can tell I can't use that because I get the error...

*XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/api/login/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.  Origin 'localhost' is therefore not allowed access.*

**Edit:**

```
$('#mybutton').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://example.com/api/login/",
            type: "POST",
            data: "name=user%40domain.com&pass=apassword",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function (result) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, tranStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: I think the real question is why do you want to do that?

Comment: @frenchie, I'm trying to authenticate with another server. They requested I send them a username and password, and they authenticate and give back an id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can submit the form to the other website, but you *cannot* access the result in your page unless the target site allows you to (and you're using `ajax`). The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents exactly this situation. The target site *could* allow you access via [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/).

You can either submit the form and relinquish control entirely (a normal form submit), **or** you can use `ajax` and be subject to the SOP (unless the site uses CORS to allow it).

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I'm just trying to understand where the issue is. Why would I be able to initiate a POST from a site such as http://www.hurl.it/, and receive the desired result? When I attempt to use .ajax(), it acts as if I didn't specify any parameters. I'll update the original question with what I was attempting there.

Comment: @moopasta: hurl.it is presumably doing the request server-side, not client-side (e.g., you say "go get this" and it sends a request to its server saying "go get this" and it server does the actual query). The SOP only applies client-side.

Comment: Perfect! Got it thanks for the help!  Not sure I didn't understand when you said it the first time. ;-/

Comment: @moopasta: I didn't call out the client-side bit. :-) Best,